# Why shift, take absolute value and perform log transform to the frequency spectrum of an image obtained by fft2 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft, spectrum

I have to obtain the frequency spectrum of a grayscale image using FFT in MATLAB and plot the spectrum. I used  `fft2()` and plotted the output.

I watched a tutorial on plotting frequency spectrum and in that, they perform `fftshit()`, take the absolute value, apply a log transformation, scale pixels using `mat2gray()` and then convert into uint8 before plotting the spectrum.
`im2uint8(mat2gray(log(abs(fft_shifted)+1)))`

My question is, is that necessary to perform all those steps before plotting the frequency spectrum? I know `fftshift()` is used to center the spectrum around 0th frequency coefficient. What is the use of performing other functions?

I plotted the frequency spectrum without shifting, after shifting, and after applying the above-mentioned steps.

[image: Outputs]

After this, I have to apply a low pass filter to the grayscale image and compare frequency spectrums. (This is a homework question)

Comment: `abs` gives you the *magnitude* of the complex FFT output, and using a log scale gives you much more dynamic range when displaying the magnitudes using 8 bit grey scale pixels.

Comment: The first two images you show have a lot of clipped values—many different values are all shown as white, and many others as black. If you linearly stretch the values from max=white to min=black, you will see only one pixel white, and the rest will be black or nearly black. The log transform allows viewing values with such large difference in magnitude.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for the explanation. Could you please explain to me what is represented by axes in the final plot? Do the x-axis display frequency and the y-axis display amplitude?

Comment: The gray value (intensity) is the amplitude. You compute the FFT of a 2D array, and so have two different spatial frequencies (frequency along x and along y), which are plotted along the new x and y.